# Trying to Scrape all the text under a particular <div>, while ignoring HTML tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying to use lxml in Python 3.5 to scrape a website, but I am having problems getting satisfactory results from a particular part of the website.

This is the basic formatting for that section:

```
<div class="field-clearfix">
    <div class="field-label">Heading</div>
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">
        <p>
        Text script <a href="URL" target=\"_blank\>[ABCD]</a>.
        Another text script <a href="URL" target=\"_blank\>[BCDE]</a>, text. 
        Another text text script <a href="URL" target=\"_blank\>[FGHI]</a>, text.
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Right now I use this:

```
page = requests.get(URL_TO_SCRAPE)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
output = tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"field-clearfix")]/div[2]/div/p/text()')
```

But that of course, only returns `Text script`. What I'd really like is for the output to include all non-HTML tagged text:

`Text script [ABCD] Another text script [BCDE], text. Another text text script [FGHI], text.`

I'm very much new to Python and scraping, so I suspect there's a really easy solution with lxml that I'm not getting here. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all the text nodes under an element and join:

```
"".join(tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"field-clearfix")]/div[2]/div/p//text()'))
                                                   # NOTE THIS EXTRA SLASH^
```

Note that *your HTML is not well-formed* and should be fixed for this to work. It works for me for this fixed version of your HTML:

```
<div class="field-clearfix">
    <div class="field-label">Heading</div>
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">
        <p>
        Text script <a href="URL" target="_blank">[ABCD]</a>.
        Another text script <a href="URL" target="_blank">[BCDE]</a>, text.
        Another text text script <a href="URL" target="_blank">[FGHI]</a>, text.
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works great with the site I'm scraping! If I could ask another question - I wanted to get rid of the bracketed sections ([ABCD], [BCDE], etc) how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @JohnSmith well, `"".join(root.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"field-clearfix")]/div[2]/div/p/text()'))` should work, please give it a try.

Comment: Yep, that works too. Thanks. I'm really quite a noob at all this.

Answer (score 1):

Using @alexcxe's amended HTML, this does the trick:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = '''<div class="field-clearfix">
    <div class="field-label">Heading</div>
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">
        <p>
        Text script <a href="URL" target="_blank">[ABCD]</a>.
        Another text script <a href="URL" target="_blank">[BCDE]</a>, text.
        Another text text script <a href="URL" target="_blank">[FGHI]</a>, text.
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser')

paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')

result = [x.text for x in paragraphs]

result = " ".join(x for x in result[0].split())
```

Check out `result`:

```
>>> result
'Text script [ABCD]. Another text script [BCDE], text. Another text text script [FGHI], text.'
```